# How can I remove all lines not containing email:password in notepad++ or Emeditor

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, editing, notepad

Full Example File Containing:

```
test@live.com:testing1
Yse@rur:userto
astr@oSt@yahoo.fr:str@st5es
@username1:password2
user2:@pass3
name@yahoo.com:1password
my@example
user@gmail.com:password
!@#$%^
Star:userfor1
names@hotmail.com:usepass1
\https]
trying@web.de:testing@
Ge@rT@y:p@ssword
us@r!to$:!@troll
1800t0p@m@:1800t0p
email@email.ru:super@1to
@st@rs:to!e@rth
gountr@mail.de:euar@tres@
S@ur:info@tro
known@web.net:scroll2
F@st@tr@y:sla@ys#
general@mail.it:stark6d8r@
```

Need Result Lefted:

```
test@live.com:testing1

astr@oSt@yahoo.fr:str@st5es


name@yahoo.com:1password

user@gmail.com:password


names@hotmail.com:usepass1

trying@web.de:testing@
```

Need Result Cut:

```
Yse@rur:userto
@username1:password2
user2:@pass3
my@example
!@#$%^
Star:userfor1
\https]
Ge@rT@y:p@ssword
us@r!to$:!@troll
1800t0p@m@:1800t0p
@st@rs:to!e@rth
S@ur:info@tro
F@st@tr@y:sla@ys#
```

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: because the answers didn't help and i tryied to make the question more deep and clear ?

Comment: The point is the answers **did** work with your **original** data set. You cannot expect people to keep changing their answers every time you change the data set.

Comment: so can i make new question for it or what ?

Comment: It's a bit late for that now ...

Comment: Can you phrase the exact rules that you want for your matches ? Examples are nice, and required for a correct answers, but just dumping them is quite confusing.

Comment: Why `Yse@rur:userto` and `Ge@rT@y:p@ssword` should be deleted but not `astr@oSt@yahoo.fr:str@st5es`

Comment: its answered currect now and i am sorry if i bothered or edit the question
my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

**Edit according to revised question:** (I guess you want a dot in the domain)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!\S+@\S+?\.\S+?:)\S+\R`
- Replace with: `EMPY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
(?!     : start negative lookahead, make sure we have NOT
  \S+   : 1 or more non space character
  @     : literally @
  \S+?  : 1 or more non space character, not greedy
  \.    : a dot
  \S+?  : 1 or more non space character, not greedy
  :     : literally :
)       : end lookahead
\S+     : 1 or more non space character
\R      : any kind of line break
```

**Result for given example:**

```
test@live.com:testing1
astr@oSt@yahoo.fr:str@st5es
name@yahoo.com:1password
user@gmail.com:password
names@hotmail.com:usepass1
trying@web.de:testing@
email@email.ru:super@1to
gountr@mail.de:euar@tres@
known@web.net:scroll2
general@mail.it:stark6d8r@
```

Comment: not working its skip some

Comment: which ones does it skips ?

Comment: @DeathRival: May be, but you've change the request. In your edited question, you have 23 inputs, 6 to be left, 13 to be deleted that isn't consistent.

Comment: yeah my bad i was should describe the question more deep and clear

Comment: Thanks So Much Man it Help Now idk what to say i really appreciate it <3